# MySQL Replication fails intermittently with HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND when inserting from a tmp table

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-rds

I'm running mysql 5.6 onn AWS RDS.  I have a mysql slave via a readreplica in RDS as well.  Replication to the slave gets an error when running a stored proc that inserts from a temporary table into a non-temporary table.

My reading of the mysql documentation is that this case is handled as long as we use mixed mode binlogging (which we do).  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-log-mixed.html

Is this a mysql bug or am I missing something?  Is this approach simply not supported when using mysql slaves?

The stored proc that is causing trouble is doing something like this, where MySummaryTable is the non-temp table and tmp_locations_table is the temp one:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_locations_table

INSERT INTO MySummaryTable (
  accountID,
  locationID
)
SELECT
  row_data.accountID,
  row_data.locationID
FROM tmp_locations_table row_data
GROUP BY
  row_data.accountID,
  row_data.locationID
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  locationID=123
```

The exact mysql error I'm seeing isn't particularly helpful: Could not execute Update_rows event on table myschema.MySummaryTable; Can't find record in 'MySummaryTable', Error_code: 1032; handler error HA_ERR_KEY_NOT_FOUND; the event's master log blahblahblah

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with the scenario, as long as your binlog format is either mixed or row, and the tables are InnoDB, but have you verified that the MySummaryTable currently contains identical data on master and slave?  If not, that's the first problem to solve, since replication *requires* identical data sets fot anything replication touches.